# Looking to save coordinates/layout to make temporal networks in Igraph with DRL

Tags: r, networking, igraph, temporal

I would like to create temporal networks in R but the only resources I've found works with FR or KK graphs. However, my primary graph that I would like to base the layout from is a DRL layout. How could I code this in R to keep the layouts?

Thank you

Added:

Code:

```
drl <- layout.drl(netfull, options=list(simmer.attraction=0))
plot(netfull, edge.arrow.size=2, vertex.size=.5, vertex.label.cex=.3, vertex.label.dist=.1, vertex.lable.degree=pi, layout=drl)
plot(net7, edge.arrow.size=2, vertex.size=.5,vertex.label.cex=.3, vertex.label.dist=.1, vertex.lable.degree=pi, layout=drl)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just explicitly compute your layout before plotting and then use the `layout` argument when you want to plot. DRL is one of the standard options provided by igraph.

```
library(igraph)

## create test graph
set.seed(1234)
g = erdos.renyi.game(15, 0.2, type = "gnp")

## Create a reusable layout for the graph
LO = layout_with_drl(g)

## plot using the layout
plot(g, layout=LO)
```

[image: DRL layout]

### Edit

Based on the discussion in the comments, I have a different understanding of the question. I think that the question is this: Given a graph g and a subgraph g2 print both g and g2 with the corresponding nodes in the same place. This extra response addresses that.

> Start with the example above to create the graph g and the layout LO.

Now we want to take a subgraph and print it with the corresponding nodes in the same place.   I will use as an example the graph that we get by removing nodes 2, 9, and 15.

If we simply remove those nodes, the new graph will have 12 nodes and they will have node IDs 1-12.  In order to preserve the original numbering, we need to save the node IDs as labels.

```
V(g)$label = 1:15
```

Now let's create the subgraph by removing nodes 2,9 and 15.

```
g2  = induced_subgraph(g, V(g)[-c(2,9,15)])
```

We want to reuse the layout LO, but LO has the positions for all 15 original nodes. We want to select only the part for the remaining nodes in g2.

```
LO2 = LO[-c(2,9,15),]
```

Now we are ready to plot the original graph and the reduced graph so that the nodes line up.

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2), mar=c(2,1,2,1))
plot(g, layout=LO, frame=TRUE)
plot(g2, layout=LO2, frame=TRUE)
```

[image: Matched graphs]

Comment: I am currently getting issues where layout stays but the node placement changes. How can I fix that? I just uploaded images

Comment: Are you rerunning the `layout_with_drl(g)` code each time?   You are only supposed to run that once.  If not, then please post your code or modify mine to give an example of what you are seeing.

Comment: It looks to me like the nodes _are_ placed the same in your two graphs. The edges in the second graph look incoherent, but the nodes look like they are in the same place for both graphs.

Comment: Yes, the node layout is the same but actual nodes are not placed in the same spot as the first graph (for example, node 1 is not placed in the same spot in the second graph), resulting in the incoherent edges

Comment: You must have the nodes in different orders for the two graphs. Can you make a small example for graphs 1 & 2?

Comment: I just tried reordering the nodes in the two graphs. Could it be that the graphs have a different amount of nodes? I want graph 2 to basically be a reduction of graph 1 after taking out a couple hundred edges and some nodes.

Comment: Edited answer. Is this what you are looking for?