# Hide vertices from plot.igraph conditional on vertex attribute without deleting them

Tags: r, igraph

I have an igraph plot that is geographically laid out based on its latitude and longitude coordinates. I now want to hide certain points from one time period, while preserving the layout of the graph. I would therefore not like to delete the vertices from the network, but merely make them invisible in this particular plot rendering, conditional on a vertex attribute. Furthermore, the color attribute is already set to capture another variable, so I cannot use that to hide the points.

My plot is generated according to the following code:

```
lo <- layout.norm(as.matrix(g[, c("longitude","latitude")]))
plot.igraph(g, layout=lo, vertex.label=NA,rescale=T, vertex.size = 4)
```

The time attribute is a numerical variable stored in `V(g)$period`

Is there code I can put within the `plot.igraph` function to hide vertices for which `V(g)$period` == 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update.
Building upon Szabolcs's answer.

```
library(igraph)
## reproducible example
g         <- make_graph("Zachary")
V(g)$name <- V(g)
set.seed(10)
lyt       <- layout_with_drl(g)
V(g)$x    <- lyt[,1]
V(g)$y    <- lyt[,2]
plot(g)
del_vs    <- c(4, 8, 9, 19, 24, 33)
dev.new(); plot(g - del_vs, main = paste("Zachary minus", toString(del_vs)))
```

---

Try invisible inkt, e.g. print hidden objects in background color.
Or try this.

```
library(igraph)
## reproducible example.
g         <- make_graph("Zachary")
V(g)$name <- V(g)
set.seed(10)
lyt       <- layout_with_drl(g)
plot(g, layout=lyt)

## delete vertices and preserve layout.
del_vs    <- c(9, 19, 24, 33)
g2        <- g - del_vs
g2$main   <-  paste("Zachary minus", toString(del_vs))
g2$layout <- matrix(lyt[-del_vs,], ncol=2)
dev.new(); plot(g2)
```

See also:

[Looking to save coordinates/layout to make temporal networks in Igraph with DRL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48939227/looking-to-save-coordinates-layout-to-make-temporal-networks-in-igraph-with-drl)
.

Comment: You could easily create your own plot procedure `my_plot(g, layout=layout_with_drl(g), del_vs=c())`.

Answer (score 2):

You can store the coordinates in the `x` and `y` vertex attributes. Then they will be used by `plot` automatically, and they will be preserved when you delete vertices.

For example:

```
g<-make_ring(4)
V(g)$x <- c(0,0,1,1)
V(g)$y <- c(0,1,0,1)
```

```
plot(g)
```

[image]

```
plot(delete_vertices(g,1))
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for this! Now, is there a way to delete the vertices of choice based on their vertex attribute (in my case the period variable) rather than through indexing?

Comment: @flâneur If you have a numerical vertex attribute called `foo`, you could select vertices with a `foo` value less than 10 using `V(g)[foo < 10]`.  Evaluate `?'[.igraph.vs'` for more details.